# Natural Transformation in a Programming Language?

Tags: category-theory, examples-counterexamples

I'm trying to solve some exercises about category theory, more specifically covering functors, natural transformations and monads. I'm stuck at one that goes as follows:

Ex.: Suppose you have a Programming Language P, and the category $P^C$: the category where objects are types of P and morphisms functions between these types. Now, consider the Functor $List: P^C \to P^C$, that maps a type $A$ to the lists of type $A$ ($List\ A$). Also, consider the identity functor $Id_{P^C}: P^C \to P^C$.

Question: Is it possible to define a natural transformation $\theta: List \to id_{P^C}$ ?

As far as I understand, the commutative diagram for that transformation is given by the one below:

$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{lll}
List\ A\ & \ra{\theta_A} & A \\
\da{fmap\ f} & & \da{f} \\
List\ B\ & \ra{\theta_B} & B \\
\end{array}
$$

Now, if I take type $A$ to be Integers, and type $B$ to be Booleans, I could define a function $f$ "isEven" that, given an integer $n$, returns "true" if $n$ is even, and "false" otherwise. Applying that through $fmap\ f$ would give me a $List Boolean$. Applying the natural transformation $head$, that takes the first element of a $List$ would make the diagram commute for the given example, if the list is not empty. But if it is empty, the diagram wouldn't commute, right?

Moreover, would it be a valid natural transformation?

Could you give me any help in finding a valid one?

Comment: Why wouldn't the diagram commute if the list was empty?

Comment: I thought that it would not commute because an empty list is not exactly of the type  $A$ (What type is it?).

Comment: For every type $A$, there is an empty list of type $\mathrm{List}(A)$. The trouble with your diagram is that the function $\mathrm{head}$ is only defined on *nonempty* lists. So it's not actually an arrow $\mathrm{List}(A)\to A$ in your category, unless you define $\text{head}(\{\}) = a$ for some special value $a$ of type $A$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no natural transformation $\theta\colon \mathrm{List}\to \mathrm{id}_{P^C}$. As suggested by the diagram in your question, the reason comes down to empty lists. For every type $A$, we need a component of the natural transformation $\theta_A\colon \mathrm{List}(A)\to A$, and in particular $\theta_A$ needs to map the empty list to some element of $A$.

If your programming language includes an empty type $\emptyset$, then we're already sunk: the type $\mathrm{List}(\emptyset)$ is nonempty, since it includes the empty list, but there can be no function from a nonempty type to an empty type (there's no possible value of $\theta_\emptyset(\{\})$.

But even if your programming language doesn't include an empty type, there's still an issue with "naturally" picking an element $\theta_A(\{\})$ of every type $A$. Indeed, consider the type $\mathrm{Bool}$ and the "not" function $\lnot\colon \mathrm{Bool}\to \mathrm{Bool}$ defined by $\lnot(\top) = \bot$ and $\lnot(\bot) = \top$. We want the following diagram to commute:

$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{lll}
\mathrm{List}(\mathrm{Bool}) & \ra{\theta_\mathrm{Bool}} & \mathrm{Bool} \\
\da{\mathrm{map}(\lnot)} & & \da{\lnot} \\
\mathrm{List}(\mathrm{Bool}) & \ra{\theta_\mathrm{Bool}} & \mathrm{Bool} \\
\end{array}
$$

But $(\mathrm{map}(\lnot))(\{\}) = \{\}$, so commutativity of the diagram says that $$ \lnot\theta_{\mathrm{Bool}}(\{\}) = \theta_\mathrm{Bool}((\mathrm{map}(\lnot))(\{\})) = \theta_\mathrm{Bool}(\{\}),$$
i.e. $\top = \bot$, which is a contradiction.

I used $\mathrm{Bool}$ here for simplicity. But actually the same argument works as long as you have any type $A$ in your language such that for every $a\in A$ there is some function $f\colon A\to A$ such that $f(a) \neq a$. If your programming language allows for constant functions, then all you need is to have a type with at least $2$ elements in it, since for every $a\in A$ you can use the function $f(x) = b$ for some $b\neq a$.

Comment: This is oversimplified.  Types and functions in a programming language do not necessarily (in fact usually don't) naively map to sets and set functions.  For example, a common semantics for types and functions which allows even talking about `head` is complete partial orders (CPOs) and supremum-preserving functions.  You can easily verify that `head` is indeed a natural transformation in the category of CPOs.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Derek. However, I'm a bit confused now. Could you ellaborate on that (perhaps in an answer)?

Comment: @DerekElkins The questions defines $P^C$ as "the category where objects are types of $P$ and morphisms functions between these types". I gave an answer for this category. There are more sophisticated ways of encoding programming languages in categories, to be sure - but if Lonatico had CPOs (for example) in mind, I would expect the question to have reflected this.

Comment: @AlexKruckman "The category where objects are types of $P$ and morphisms functions between these types" is simply not a well-defined notion, particularly when no particular programming language has been specified. I'd expect you to state how you are interpreting it. If you do choose Set, that's fine, but you should then mention that this limits to total functions and thus excludes `head`. From there, it would also not hurt to indicate how partial functions like `head` could be incorporated, e.g. via CPO. The question clearly reflected the possibility of partial functions.

Answer (score 1):

Consider `Vecₙ` to be the type of lists/vectors of length `n`.
Let `_‼ₙ_` be the indexing operation on `Vecₙ`; that is, if
`xs : Vecₙ A` is a vector of `n` elements of type `A` and
`i ≤ n`, then `xs ‼ₙ i` is an element of `A`, namely the `i`-th component of
the vector.

Observe that for any pair `i, n` with `i ≤ n`, we have a natural transformation

```
(‼ₙ i) : Vecₙ ⟶ Id
```

Indeed, for let `f : A → B` be any old plain
function, then the commutativity condition amounts to

```
map f xs ‼ₙ i = f (xs ‼ₙ i)
```

i.e., transforming all elements by `f` then getting the `i`-th element is the same
as getting the `i`-th element and transforming it by `f`.

We avoided having to worry about non-empty lists or having default values
---which means we can only consider functions that "preserve" default values---
by using dependent types. That is, for any `n`, we have a type-former `Vecₙ`.
Yet, `Vec` itself can be construed as a "dependent type" since it depends on
a value, not a type, `n`. Dependently-typed programming languages are gaining popularity; [Agda](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=Main.HomePage) for example.